# sharepoint list view search box water mark remove

Tags: sharepoint-search, sharepoint-list

how to remove "find an item" water mark in the List View ootb search box?

Answer (score 1):

Using CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
.ms-InlineSearch-SearchBox-EmptyUnfocused {
    display:none;
}
.ms-inlineSearch-searchImgSpanStandard {
    float:right;
}
</style>
```

Using JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function () {

    //Create a function to be able to hide the text if the field loses focus and would need to be hidden again
    function clearSearchbox() {
        //Create a reference to the input search field
        listSearch = document.querySelector('input[id^="inplaceSearchDiv"].ms-InlineSearch-SearchBox-EmptyUnfocused');
        listSearch.value = '';
    };

    //Clear the search input when the page has loaded
    clearSearchbox();

    //Attach en event that to hide the text if the search input loses focus / clicked elsewhere on the page
    listSearch.addEventListener("focusout", clearSearchbox);

};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do some custom JavaScript. You can add this JavaScript using Content Editor or using JSLINK.

```
$("#inplaceSearchDiv_WPQ1_lsinput").value= " "
```

Above code will make List View OOTB search Box Empty.